# How to replace vector of regexps with one single expression?

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I have something like 100+ different villages in my material. In order for my visualizations to make sense, I need to group them together as 22 municipalities, something like this:

```
TROLLHÄTTAN<-toupper(c("Trollhättan","Sjuntorp","Velanda","Åsaka","Upphärad"))
UDDEVALLA<-toupper(c("UDDEVALLA","KURVERÖD","AMMENÄS","FAGERHULT","LANESUND OCH ÖVERBY",
"LANESUND","ÖVERBY","RESTENÄS OCH ULVESUND","RESTENÄS","ULVESUND","STRAND","UTBY","HOGSTORP","SUND","SMEDSERÖD"))
VÄNERSBORG<-toupper(c("Vänersborg","Vargön","Brålanda","Frändefors","Nordkroken","Katrinedal"))
LYSEKIL<-toupper(c("Lysekil", "Brastad", "Grundsund", "Fiskebäckskil"))
FÄRGELANDA<-toupper(c("Färgelanda","Högsäter","Ödeborg","Stigen"))
MELLERUD<-toupper(c("Mellerud","Dals Rostock","Åsensbruk"))
ED<-toupper(c("Ed"))
BENGTSFORS<-toupper(c("Bengtsfors","Dals Långed","Billingsfors","Bäckefors","Skåpafors"))
ÅMÅL<-toupper(c("Åmål","Tösse","Fengersfors"))
STRÖMSTAD<-toupper(c("Strömstad","Skee","Kebal","Stare"))
TANUM<-toupper(c("Grebbestad","Tanumshede","Fjällbacka","Hamburgsund","Rabbalshede"))
SOTENÄS<-toupper(c("Hunnebostrand","Kungshamn","Smögen","Malmön","Bovallstrand"))
MUNKEDAL<-toupper(c("Munkedal","Dingle","Hällevadsholm","Hedekas","Torreby"))
ORUST<-toupper(c("Svanesund","Ellös","Hälleviksstrand","Mollösund","Henån","Höggeröd","Vindön och Töllås","Varekil","Vindön","Töllås"))
LILLA_EDET<-toupper(c("Lilla Edet","Lödöse","Lilla Edet västra","Göta","Nygård","Hjärtum"))
ALE<-toupper(c("Ale","Nödinge-Nol","Surte","Älvängen","Skepplanda","Alvhem"))
STENUNGSUND<-toupper(c("Jörlanda","Stora Höga","Timmervik","Spekeröd","Stenungsund","Stenungsön","Svartehallen","Svenshögen","Ucklum","Ödsmål"))
TJÖRN<-toupper(c("Bleket","Djupvik och Fagerfjäll","Höviksnäs","Klövedal","Kyrkesund och Bö","Kållekärr","Myggenäs","Rönnäng","Skärhamn","Stora Dyrön",
"Djupvik","Fagerfjäll","Kyrkesund","Bö"))
KUNGÄLV<-toupper(c("Aröd och Timmervik","Diseröd","Duvesjön","Harestad och Nereby","Kareby","Kode","Kovikshamn","Kungälv","Kärna",
"Lundby","Marstrand","Marstrand", "Arvidsvik","Risby","Rishammar","Signehög och Norrmannebo","Solberga","Tjuvkil","Ödsmål och Åseby",
"Ödsmåls mosse och Rörtången","Aröd","Timmervik","Harestad","Nereby","Signehög","Norrmannebo","Ödsmål","Åseby","Ödsmåls mosse","Rörtången"))
ALINGSÅS<-toupper(c("Alingsås","Ingared","Sollebrunn","Västra Bodarna","Gräfsnäs","Hemsjö","Stora Mellby","Hjälmared","Långared","Svanvik",
"Ryd","Magra"))
VARA<-toupper(c("Vara","Kvänum","Tråvad","Jung","Vedum","Larv","Stora Levene","Emtunga","Arentorp"))
ESSUNGA<-toupper(c("Nossebro","Främmestad","Jonslund"))
VÅRGÅRDA<-toupper(c("Vårgårda","Östadkulle","Horla"))
GRÄSTORP<-toupper(c("GRÄSTORP"))
LIDKÖPING<-toupper(c("Lidköping","Lidköping norra","Vinninga","Järpås","Filsbäck","Örslösa","Saleby"))
GÖTEBORG<-toupper(c("Göteborg","Gunnared och Hammarkullen","Torslanda","Billdal","Olofstorp","Donsö","Nolvik","Styrsö","Angered",
"Brännö","Säve","Helgered","Tumlehed","Asperö","Stenared","Vrångö","Gundal och Högås","Gunnared","Hammarkullen","Gundal","Högås"))
```

I try to replace the village name vector with the name of the municipality via mgsub (textclean version), but I run into problems. For instance "strand" (a village name) is also a popular suffix. This means that "HUNNEBOSTRAND" gets converted to "HUNNEBOUDDEVALLA" which is of course less than optimal.

I try to write my vectors with regular expressions instead:

```
LYSEKIL<-toupper(c("^Lysekil$", "^Brastad$", "^Grundsund$", "^Fiskebäckskil$"))
```

I find that the textclean version of mgsub can't handle regular expressions. I change to the mgsub package, which want my vectors to be the same length, which isn't what I want. The qdap version of mgsub seems to function in a similar fashion.

Is there any way around this?

Original data (with sensitive parts removed)

structure(list(CITY = c("HENÅN                      ", NA, "HENÅN                      ", 
"ÄLVÄNGEN                   ", NA, "TROLLHÄTTAN                "
), ZIPCODE = c(47395L, NA, 47332L, 44636L, NA, 46157L), COURSEOFFERING_ID = c(97113L, 
97113L, 97113L, 97113L, 97113L, 97113L)), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 
9L, 12L, 15L, 18L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the problem of a village name also being a suffix, you can anchor the start and end of these names with `^` and `$` (you had the right idea there). But to replace the village names with the name of their corresponding municipality, you need to use the function `gsub()` (or `stringr::str_replace_all()`). To play safe and not have to worry about which names will be a problem, simply anchor all village names with `^` and `$`.

Here is an option:

1. Create a vector with your 100+ village names (I am using your first 2 vectors as example):

```
all_village_names <- c(
  "Trollhättan", "Sjuntorp", "Velanda", "Åsaka", "Upphärad",  "UDDEVALLA",
  "KURVERÖD", "AMMENÄS", "FAGERHULT", "LANESUND OCH ÖVERBY", "LANESUND",
  "ÖVERBY", "RESTENÄS OCH ULVESUND", "RESTENÄS", "ULVESUND", "STRAND",
  "UTBY", "HOGSTORP", "SUND", "SMEDSERÖD"
)
```

2. use a series of `gsub()` to replace them by their corresponding municipality names (here again, I am using your first 2 lines of code):

```
library(dplyr)

all_village_names %>%
  gsub("^Trollhättan$|^Sjuntorp$|^Velanda$|^Åsaka$|^Upphärad$", "TROLLHÄTTAN", .) %>%
  gsub("^UDDEVALLA$|^KURVERÖD$|^AMMENÄS$|^FAGERHULT$|^LANESUND OCH ÖVERBY$|^LANESUND$|^ÖVERBY$|^RESTENÄS OCH ULVESUND$|^RESTENÄS$|^ULVESUND$|^STRAND$|^UTBY$|^HOGSTORP$|^SUND$|^SMEDSERÖD$", "UDDEVALLA", .)
```

You will end up with a vector of 100+ elements (one for each of your initial village), but the vector will only be made up of your 22 municipality names.

With the sample data I used, this gives you:

```
[1] "TROLLHÄTTAN" "TROLLHÄTTAN" "TROLLHÄTTAN" "TROLLHÄTTAN" "TROLLHÄTTAN"
 [6] "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"  
[11] "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"  
[16] "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"   "UDDEVALLA"
```

Without the anchoring, `LANESUND` was turned into `LANEUDDEVALLA` (since `SUND` is turned into `UDDEVALLA`). But the anchoring prevents that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201084/discussion-on-answer-by-prosoitos-how-to-replace-vector-of-regexps-with-one-sing).